# Get VM fields value in a class that extends AbstractIssueAction

Tags: java, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I am working with *Atlassian's JIRA* product. I have a class that extends `AbstractIssueAction`, so I can do all basic operations inside that class.

My problem is that I can not access the velocity template fields values (e.g. from a text field) from my class.

Below is my `.vm` :

```
<form method="get" class="aui">
    <div class="issues">
        <textarea  id="h-feditor1" name="name" rows="18" cols="120"/>
        #if($bodyContent)
            $bodyContent.bodyContent
        #end
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <br>

    <a href="$instance.doSaveToDb()" id="add-quote-line-item" class="aui-button add-quote-     line-item">$i18n.getText("lineItem.form.button.add")</a>

</form>
```

And my method in the `AbstractIssueAction` class...

```
public String doSaveToDb() {
    if (content1 != null) {
        //Object content12 = session.getAttribute("name");

        List<BodyContent> tempBodyContent = this.adminService.getBodyContent();

        if (tempBodyContent.size() > 0 ) {
            bodyContent = tempBodyContent.get(0);
            bodyContent.setBodyContent(content1);
            bodyContent.save();
        } else {
            this.adminService.createTermsConditons(content1, "");
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

I use this to populate the velocity template and it works fine problem is to get the field value from the template back to the java class (method)

Comment: Where is the "velocity" information in your form?

Comment: I use this to populate the velocity template and it works fine problem is to get the field value from the template back to the java class (method)

protected void populateVelocityParams(Map params) {
 List<BodyContent> tempTermsConditions = this.adminService.getBodyContent();

 BodyContent bodyContent = null;


 if(tempTermsConditions.size() > 0 ){
     bodyContent = tempTermsConditions.get(0);
 }

 String myData = "";

 params.put("instance", this);
 params.put("bodyContent", bodyContent);



    }